# Meteor error in windows while trying to start up

Tags: meteor

All of sudden meteor app is failing to run following command. Os is windows 8.1.

```
C:\myproject> meteor

C:\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:278
                        throw(ex);
                              ^
Error: Couldn't run netstat -ano: {}
    at Object.Future.wait (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\dev_bundle\lib\node_modules\fibers\future.js:398:15)
    at findMongoPids (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:120:16)
    at findMongoAndKillItDead (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:236:14)
    at launchOneMongoAndWaitForReadyForInitiate (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:360:7)
    at launchMongo (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:612:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._startOrRestart (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:712:19)
    at [object Object]._.extend.start (C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:670:10)
    at C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-all.js:199:26
    - - - - -
    at C:\\.meteor\packages\meteor-tool\1.1.3\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools\run-mongo.js:89:28
    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:654:7)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:766:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:833:5)
```

Answer (score 3):

I had the above issue on a Windows 8.1 machine and the following github issue/solution worked for me
[github post](https://github.com/lokenx/plexrequests-meteor/issues/65)

I'll repeat the solution:
**damiantje99** commented on May 10:
The fix is the following:

Go to: C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Local\ .meteor\packages\meteor-tool\VERSION\mt-os.windows.x86_32\tools

In there you have a file called run-mongo.js

Open that file with notepad++ or anything similair.

Then on line 87 find the text:

child_process.exec('netstat -ano', function (error, stdout, stderr) {

And replace it with

child_process.exec('netstat -ano', {maxBuffer: 1024 * 1024}, function (error, stdout, stderr) {

Comment: Ran into this problem again! Set the same line to: {maxBuffer: 2048 * 2048} and again the app started fine.

Comment: I have found it in \tools\runners

Answer (score 0):

can you run without error, in a command line and give the output:

```
netstat -ano
```

If it works fine manually, try a reboot (worked in my case, meteor couldn't see netstat right after install on windows 8.1)

Comment: it runs. output is too huge. shall i post everything? By the way meteor was working all of a sudden it broke.

Comment: ok, so if it ran before, it is not netstat the problem.
what did you change before it began to fail ? did you try to revert the code ? installed packages ?

Comment: I wrote new code - REST API using Iron-Route package. While trying to test it whole thing broke. Not just current project broke, other projects are also not running even after reinstallation of Meteor and restarting PC.

But same code is working fine in Mac.

Comment: Is there a global lock file on mongo which may be causing this issue?